# finding the difference in two arrays of hashes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have two Arrays `oldArray` and `newArray`. When a new value gets put into `newArray` I want to compare against `oldArray` and pull out the new value.

In these arrays I am storing hashes.

For example.

```
oldArray = []
newArray = [{"one": 1}]
```

I need to find the new element, which is `{"one": 1}`

Using underscore.js I can do something like this:

```
newElement = _.difference(newValue, oldValue)
```

That works fine the first time, but when I go back and add more to the arrays:

```
oldArray = [{"one": 1}]
newArray = [{"one": 1},{"two": 2}]
```

And do the same thing  `newElement = _.difference(newValue, oldValue)`

I get `[{"one": 1},{"two": 2}]` coming back as new objects... Is it because I am comparing objects and not values? Is there a better way to do this.

The above is an example but from my app I have pulled this from console

```
oldValue map.js:85
[Object]
0: Object
$$hashKey: "007"
address: "england"
latLng: GeoCode
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

newValue map.js:83
[Object, Object]

0: Object
$$hashKey: "007"
address: "england"
latLng: GeoCode
__proto__: Object

1: Object
$$hashKey: "009"
address: "france"
latLng: GeoCode
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

When I compare these two I get:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
$$hashKey: "007"
address: "england"
latLng: GeoCode
__proto__: Object

1: Object
$$hashKey: "009"
address: "france"
latLng: GeoCode
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I am using AngularJS and Underscore in this project currently.

Maybe there is a much better of doing this. I just need to pull out the "different" object from that array. So I can use it to do something else. It will not always be the last element.

**UPDATE**

I have also tried JavaScript Array Set Mathematics Library and use `.substract` but with the same results. This must mean that the hashes are changing - but they dont look like it to me

To get these `oldArray` and `newArray` I am using an Angular $watch.

Comment: Could you provide a reduced test case on something like jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$$hashKey` is always unique, then you can create two objects and make the keys of the hashes their `$$hashKey`.

```
newObject[myObject["$$hashKey"]] = myObject;
```

Then

```
var difference = _.omit(newObject, _.keys(oldObject));
```

will give you an object containing that only contains the key/value pairs that were in the newObject but not the old.

If there's not a unique key, a less convenient way would be to serialize and deserialize the objects to strings, and then use `_.difference`.

Comment: $$hashKey is always unqiue

Comment: this does work, which is really interesting. I wonder why the other function did not work

Comment: In JavaScript, comparisons between objects are done by strict identity, not by their key/value pairs. So `foo = {5 : 6}; bar = {5: 6}; foo == bar; // false`

Comment: that makes a lot of sense then! Can I call _.difference without strict identity

Comment: No, `_.difference` isn't customizable. You'd have to write an alternate version of `_.contains` that uses equality instead of identity, and create an alternate version of `_.difference` to use the new version. Nothing hard, but it's not in underscore itself.

Comment: okay, thanks :) You solution outputs an object like this: Object {0: Object} it it possible to just put put Object{Object} the key 0 changes to 1 the second time and I cant access it? Unless there is away to extract the only record?

Comment: Not sure how you're trying to use this. Note that difference will be an object with keys that are $$hashKey values. Depending on what you want to do, you might pull them out with `_.values(difference)`, or some other method. That part is up to you.  

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates the basic usage: http://jsfiddle.net/tcsFe/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a simular AngularJS challenge not long ago.  While I'm not sure that I can give you the absolute BEST answer for how to manage this, here is what I can say worked for me:

First: Be sure you are using $watch properly.  It takes 3 params:

- watchExpression – {(function()|string)} – Expression that is evaluated on each $digest cycle. A change in the return value triggers a call to the listener.
  string: Evaluated as expression
  function(scope): called with current scope as a parameter.
- listener(optional) – {(function()|string)=} – Callback called whenever the return value of the watchExpression changes.
  string: Evaluated as expression
  function(newValue, oldValue, scope): called with current and previous values as parameters.
- **objectEquality(optional)** – {boolean=} – Compare object for equality rather than for reference.

The last piece is of particular importance.  You want to be watching for objectEquality in your case, so be sure to use $watch like so:

`$scope.$watch('watchObject', fn({}), true);`

Note the use of `true` as the third param above.  See more in the [Angular Scope Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch).

Second: When diffing Angular objects, I think the answer around comparing the $$hashKeys could make a lot of sense.  You might also consider writing your own diff function, depending on what you want to return.  If you wanted to return the difference and you are only looking at diffing a basic object, try something like: [jQuery objectDiff](https://github.com/cdinger/jquery-objectdiff)

Third: If you want to compare an Object with nested Objects and/or Arrays inside of it, things will get difficult.  I wrote an unoptimized method of doing so, and I'll happily shed more light if you need it.

Good luck!